# CyberPanel stopped working as MariaDB uninstalled, when reinstalling still isn’t working…

Tags: 20.04, mariadb

So I have CyberPanel installed after 2 days MariaDB came uninstalled after reinstalling it using:

```
sudo apt install -y mariadb-server
```

I can do `sudo MySQL` which works fine, but even after restarting the LSWS still shows Error 500? Any help

Comment: well it might be missing a database as mysql et.al. are just databaseManagementSystems; perhaps reinstall cyberpanel too?

Comment: The only way to reinstall CyberPanel is to reset the OS, that’s from there official docs so yeah.. I’m pretty screwed if I cannot get this working ahah